# High Voltage Capacitor

Tags: safety

Is there a complete "donkey proof" method to discharge a HV-Capacitor?  There are several safety issues on leaving it charged where I go to school, since some students tend to tamper with anything I create, or make.  Hence, leaving out in the open is not ideal, since the HV-Capacitor will be charged when immediately after I use it.  Any advice on this safety issue would be desired.  The HV-Capacitor is attached to Jacob's Ladder?

Comment: Other than a bleeder resistor?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams What would be the necessary resistance? I have no idea what a bleeder resistor, that is why I ask.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Never mind I found it, thanks. But let me edit the question, just to make sure that I can fully make sure nobody touches anything I make

Comment: What are the parameters of your "HV" capacitor? Voltage? Capacitance? What kind of capacitor?

Comment: A Jacob's ladder usually works on AC; the inductor winding that drives the output is a short at DC, and will always discharge a capacitor there.  The energy content of the capacitor is more important for safety than the  'high voltage'; what is the C value?

Comment: @Whit3rd It is from a microwave oven. I think it's 1 F.

Comment: Microwave caps tend to come with internal bleeder resistors (safety first). The one's I've seen tend to be 10Meg or so. The average microwave cap can hit 2.4kV or more and is in the range of a microfarad or so. A 10Meg resistor across a 1uF cap will take 10 seconds to drop to ~1/3 of it's initial voltage (t=RC), and should be below 60V after 400 (40*t) seconds or so which is reasonably "touch safe" (Vfinal = Vinitial*(e^(RC/t)) - Vinitial = 2400*(1-e^(10/400)) - 2400 = 60V)

Comment: @Sam Thanks you have no idea how many people go "What does that do? (while pointing, and then touching)

Comment: Mate, sounds like you're dealing with engineers, we fiddle with *everything!* Just put a nice big sign on it like this one http://www.electricstuff.co.uk/reallydangerous.gif "Extremely dangerous thing. Don't even think about it!" That should keep people's hands off it.

Comment: @Sam Dude your comment should be an answer...

Answer (score 1):

This is a well-known piece of equipment called, variously, a shorting stick or ground stick. You can buy them (although they're pricey) or you can make your own.

To make your own, take a 2-foot length of wooden stick, say a 1x2. To the end, fix an old multimeter probe. Connect the probe to a string of high-value resistors, say 100k. Look up the voltage rating of the resistors, and use at least as many as this implies for your working voltage. At the end of the string connect a high-voltage wire (rated for your voltage) connected to an alligator clip.

To use, fasten the clip to a handy ground point, and then touch the probe tip to the capacitor terminal. Hold for several seconds. Make sure to check the resistor string value each time you use the stick. If one of the resistors has an internal crack or a solder joint has opened up, the stick won't work and you won't know it.

Once the cap is discharged, put some sort of shorting link on it. Capacitor dielectrics will recover voltage after being discharged.

Since you're dealing with schoolchildren, you might seriously consider a commercial product. Think, "liability".